# Button Problems

Tags: html, css

I have ran into a problem with my top navigation buttons. Say I'm changing the dimensions of my window horizontally. My buttons do this.
[image]

If the browser gets too small horizontally, i want it to do something like this.

[image]

How is this achievable?

I don't want my buttons to wrap like that when changing the dimensions of the window horizontally.

summary: I want my navigation buttons not to wrap when the screen gets small horizontally but when the window does get small enough horizontally, i want the buttons to go off screen so they don't wrap together.

If you need any more information, please just ask me.
Right now I'm just giving the simple problem here.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"</meta>

        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="MOPM-ico/favicon-144.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="MOPM-ico/browserconfig.xml">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="MOPM-ico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="MOPM-ico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="310x310" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-310.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-196.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-160.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-64.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-16.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-57.png">

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

        <title>
            MOPM~
        </title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <!--header-->
            <div class="topHead">
                <img id="headertxt" src="pictures/header.png" width="100%" height="120px"/>
            </div>

            <!--header buttons-->
            <div class="headButtonSeperator">
                <div class="headButton">home</div>
                <div class="headButton">about</div>
                <div class="headButton">mod info</div>
                <div class="headButton">downloads</div>
                <div class="headButton">videos</div>
                <div class="headButton">links</div>
                <div class="headButton">dev team</div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!--content-->
        <div id="home">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('pictures/background.png');
}
/*--Classes--*/
.topHead
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #272B30;
    float: middle;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 4px dashed #1EC20B;
}

.headButtonSeperator
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    left: 509px;
}

.headButton
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #313A3D;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0px;

    border-left: 3px solid #282E30;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #282E30;

    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}


.headButton:hover
{
    width: 140px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #313A3D;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    color: #DB481B;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-family: minecraft;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #7A5E55;

    border-left: 3px solid #282E30;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #282E30;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

/*--ID's--*/
#home
{
    display: block;
    width: 918px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 500px;
    float: middle;
    z-index: -1;
}

/*--Fonts--*/
@font-face
{
        font-family: minecraft;
        src: url(fonts/minecraft.ttf);
}

@font-face
{
        font-family: McBold;
        src: url(fonts/ARCADEPI.ttf);
}

@font-face
{
        font-family: McBlock;
        src: url(fonts/Square.ttf);
}

@font-face
{
        font-family: MccBlock;
        src: url(fonts/Squareo.ttf);
}
```

Comment: i don't think stackoverflow's buttons do anything

Comment: then ill give another example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only has to do with the `width` property of the *ultimate* container of such elements, you have to set it to a definite value to prevent it from shrinking more than it should and therefore messing up your page's structure, also, it's recommended that you set your container's `overflow` attribute to `hidden` to let the rendering engine calculate the sizes and positions correctly and to prevent its contained elements' margins to trespass your container's boundaries, which also causes issues on your structure. Some examples from the website I'm working on:

Normal [(full size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yLIp.png):

[image: Image 1]

Resized window [(full size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsnAC.png):

[image: Image 2]

Code (simplified):

```
ul {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 885px;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
}

li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 162px;
    height: 162px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}
```

Where `ul` is my container and the `li`'s are my *buttons*.

Comment: and how do i do that exactly?

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more clear. But here the thing is: Just set the width of the element that contains your buttons to a definite, known value, like 900px or 100%.

Comment: overflow: hidden seems to work but the only problem now is it not adjusting to the screen. http://prntscr.com/4bb9ta and i dont want to use percentages because i dont want the screen to get too small. I  want the page to stop shrinking at some point.

Comment: Then use the ´min-width´ property. But beware, [it's not too well supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width).

Answer (score 2):

This issue, if I understand it correctly, is about `overflow`.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoxayor7/1/) which shows the differences between what you want and what you have.

The main thing you need to do is

```
.doNotWrap {  
overflow: auto;  
white-space: nowrap;  
}
```

`overflow: auto` will create a scrollbar when the parent is too small to contain the child element.
`white-space: nowrap` will not wrap the contents.

Note that this will not work if you are using `float` on the child elements (your buttons). Get rid of that. You don't need `float` and `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Yeah, I promote never using float ever for anything; If you need something like float I recommend Flex Boxses instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't match what you're seeing to what I'm seeing based on what you've posted. Sometimes it just works that way. What I've shown you works, but you have other styles in the way. Consider simplifying things - a wonderful aspect of CSS is that you should be able to do a simple example like I did on JSFiddle where you can concentrate on just how to not `wrap` your child elements.

Comment: soo... when i take away     display: inline-block The buttons bunch up in a horizontal list. When i get rid of     float it positions it weirdly.

Comment: can it be because i have two classes in my parent div?

Comment: [This is what I see](http://jsfiddle.net/6xzpfupq/1/) after I make the changes of 1) Getting rid of `float`, 2) adding `white-space: nowrap`, and 3) changing the `left` value of a container so I can see what is actually happening. (Just updated link, didn't go through before)

Comment: ok i got your method to work http://prntscr.com/4bb730 but it isn't exactly what i want. yes they donwt  wrap nor do they fit to the page like i want them to do (which i think i can center them by doing a percentage). i dont want a scroll bar if the screen gets too small.

Comment: If you don't want scrollbars, remove `overflow` from the parent. Overall, I think you're diving in too deep as a beginner, too fast. CSS requires you know the effect of everything, not just randomly add attributes. What you want could require relative positioning instead of absolute, flex box instead of inline block, etc. I'm sorry, but your code is too muddled for me to fix further.

Comment: ok i understand.. maybe i should just take time in a test.html and derp around with different attributes

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to put the style `white-space: nowrap` on the parent container.

Comment: .headButtonSeperator
    {
     width: 50%;
     height: 40px;
     background-color: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 125px;
     left: 509px;
     white-space: nowrap;
    }

this class is the div that contains the buttons but they still bunch up together.